# How can I execute methods in push notifications Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

So, I'm developing an Android app and therefore I'm using push notifications in it. Until then there is no problems, but the question is that I want notifications with buttons which will allow users to interact with the app, like start a function or do things like that. Meanwhile, I don't know how to execute a method "inside" the notification, or something similar to it.

Below there is a screenshot with a sample of the notification and the buttons I've said.

[Sample of the notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MvuN.png)

Like you can see in the picture, I need to activate a function when the user taps one of the buttons. Anyone knows how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation has a great guide for building notifications.
What you're looking for is a pending intent.

Look through the official android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#action)

Answer (score 0):

Here is tutorial that will give you step-by-step instructions.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html